# Emperical mean when using Gaussian Process regression

Tags: mean, gaussian-process

Say one has $n = 100$ values of an unknown function $f$ depending on one random variable $x$. One can compute its emperical mean as: $\mathbb{E}_n[f] = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n}f(x_i)$.
Now, one builds a surrogate model using a Gaussian Process Regression using these $n$ values denoted by $g$. Suppose we know the pdf of the input variable $x$ and we want to compute the emperical mean obtained by using the GPR model through the Monte-Carlo process $\mathbb{E}_N[g] = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{N}g(x_i)$ with $N >>1$. Do we know if $\mathbb{E}_N[g] = \mathbb{E}_n[f]$ ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Is $g$ is a GP that is fit to $\{(x_i, f(x_i)) : i=1,\dots, n\}$? What are you sampling for the Monte-Carlo process? Are you sampling from the GP posterior? Or new points $X_i$?

Comment: After re-reading what I wrote, it is not very clear. But yes, it is a GP that fits ${(x_i,f(x_i)):i=1,…,n}$. Then using this metamodel, we compute the mean from new points $X_i$ following the pdf. I guess we will not get the same mean but it might be possible to quantify the difference.

Comment: ok, that helps. Are you then looking at the mean of the GP at a particular arbitrary input, say $x_0$, or more like the mean value over the whole support of the process?

Comment: Each $g(x_i)$ in $\mathbb{E}[g]$ is computed as the mean of the GP at $x_i$. My main question is that say you have 2 models, $f$ and $g$, where $f$ is very complicated and very expensive and where $g$ is a GP regression model build using $n$ observations of $f$. Moreover, say you know the pdf of the input variable $x$, you can compute the mean  -through MC for instance- using the metamodels $f$ and $g$.The problem is evaluating $f$ is much more expensive than using $g$. Thus, I would like to know if it is possible to get a bound between the true mean $\mathbb{E}[f]$ and $\mathbb{E}_N[g]$.

Comment: Or between $\mathbb{E}[f]$ and $\mathbb{E}[g]$ (the true mean of the $g$) if we use many many evaluations of $g$ because it is very cheap.

Comment: I think $\text E[g_n(X)]$ is not quite equal to $\text E[f(X)]$ but I think that the error in the approximation decreases quickly with $n$. Intuitively I think this is because the points we observe coming from the distribution of $X$ mean that $g$ will approximate $f$ well in the parts that contribute the most to $\text E[f(X)]$. I'll post something soon, maybe just partial results if I don't get anything conclusive